# Bootstrap 3 - button, text, button with float

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make such layout:
[image: desired layout]

How can I achieve it using Bootstrap 3?

Have tried the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="well">
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center"><button class="btn btn-default">Previous</button></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">title</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center"><button class="btn btn-default">Next</button></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use class `.pull-right` and `.pull-left` with your code, and as an example:

```
<button class="btn btn-default pull-left">Previous</button>
<button class="btn btn-default pull-right">Next</button>
```

hope this give you the idea and work for you.

Comment: I know about pull-* but they didn't work either. The structure is okay then, but text is not centered vertically but lies in the top (related to buttons)

Comment: use jsfiddle or any site like it so i can see the code, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you wrap the cols inside a `row`..

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="well"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center"><button class="btn btn-default">Previous</button></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">title</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center"><button class="btn btn-default">Next</button></div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Demo** http://bootply.com/105224

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size increases.Predefined grid classes like **.row** and **.col-md-4** are available for quickly making grid layouts.

```
 <div class="titleBar"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"><button class="btn btn-primary">Button 1</button></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">Title Text</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 "><button class="btn btn-primary">Button 2</button></div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Hope this would be helpful.Also check this http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid for more details about responsive grid layout.